# ubuntu - how to uninstall deb package?

Tags: ubuntu, deb, rundeck

How can I remove a program installed with debian package?

I've installed Rundeck (http://rundeck.org/downloads.html) in my Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This site is for programming related questions. Your question is off-topic here. Please review the [help] guidelines prior to posting here, and review them at any other [se] site prior to posting there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use dpkg to manage manually installed packages.

```
dpkg --remove myPackageName
```

Comment: Please don't answer clearly off-topic questions. If you're not sure what types of questions are and are not on-topic, please review the [help/on-topic] page.

Comment: Indeed, better answered over at askubuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/22200/how-to-uninstall-a-deb-package